# ValueError using MetPy and xarray

Tags: python, python-xarray, metpy

I am trying to use some scripts from https://unidata.github.io/MetPy/latest/examples/Four_Panel_Map.html#sphx-glr-download-examples-four-panel-map-py to make weather charts but i found this problem running this script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/fedec/PycharmProjects/met2/four-panel.py", line 46, in <module>
    ds = xr.open_dataset(get_test_data('gfs_output.nc', False))
  File "C:\Users\fedec\PycharmProjects\met2\venv\lib\site-packages\xarray\backends\api.py", line 480, in open_dataset
    engine = plugins.guess_engine(filename_or_obj)
  File "C:\Users\fedec\PycharmProjects\met2\venv\lib\site-packages\xarray\backends\plugins.py", line 111, in guess_engine
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: did not find a match in any of xarray's currently installed IO backends ['scipy', 'zarr']. Consider explicitly selecting one of the installed backends via the ``engine`` parameter to xarray.open_dataset(), or installing additional IO dependencies:
http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/getting-started-guide/installing.html
http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/user-guide/io.html

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I thought that i had some issue wiht xarray, so i tried to upgrade my xarray doing this:
pip install "xarray[io]"
pip install "xarray[complete]"
But I get the same ValueError.
Python Version 3.8
Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!
Fede

Answer (score 1):

That particular datafile is netCDF-4 formatted, which isn't supported by either zarr or scipy. I'm surprised that installing `xarray[io]` or `xarray[complete]` didn't fix it. Trying manually doing `pip install netcdf4`.

(If that doesn't work, comment here and update the traceback above with the new error.)